# registered a new domain from a different provider (onlydomains.com)

Tags: godaddy, multiple-domains

I registered biowattsonline.com from GoDaddy a few months ago. I have it using Zerigo DNS. Now I have registered biowatts.cn from onlydomains.com

In Heroku (hosting a Rails application) I added 3 domains:

```
biowattsonline.com
www.biowattsonline.com
cn.biowattsonline.com
```

(I can't add another base name)

How do I configure in onlydomains.com so that I can forward biowatts.cn to biowattsonline.com or even cn.biowattsonline.com ?

```
biowatts.cn => biowattsonline.com
biowatts.cn => cn.biowattsonline.com
```

And what is the best practices around having different domains names for the same application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familier with onlydomains you mentioned, but if there is a DNS Record Type called `url forwarding` that is the answer. If there is not, you could use other dns hosting service such as [dnsever.com](http://dnsever.com), which I know that supports this kind of records.

There will be nothing wrong if you do a url forwarding to the original url since the Rails server will never care about it. So there is no additional work to do then.